# How to replace in log4j2.xml with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, mule, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to replace a value in our log4j2.xml with Gradle during build. I found a way to do that:

```
task reaplaceInLogFile {
    String apiSuffix = System.properties['apiSuffix'] ?: ''
    println "In my task"
    String contents = file('src/main/resources/log4j2.xml').getText( 'UTF-8' ) 
    println "File found"
    contents = contents.replaceAll( "svc0022_operations", "svc0022_operations${apiSuffix}")
    new File( 'src/main/resources/log4j2.xml' ).write( contents, 'UTF-8' )
}
```

However, this changes also the source file permanently and I do not want to do that. I want to change the log4j2.xml that will be included in the build zip only. I know I can use something like this:

```
tasks.withType(com.mulesoft.build.MuleZip) { task ->
    String apiSuffix = System.properties['apiSuffix'] ?: ''
    task.eachFile {
        println name
        if (name == 'mule-app.properties') {
            println "Expanding properties for API Version suffix: ${apiSuffix}"
            filter { String line ->
                line.startsWith("${serviceId}.api.suffix") ? "${serviceId}.api.suffix=${apiSuffix}" : line
            }
        }
```

But I do not know what is the type of the log4j2 file. If there is another way to do that I will be thankful!

**We are using Mule gradle plugin.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Type is not the type of the log4j2 file, but the type of the task that creates the ZIP or wherever your log4j2 file is packaged into. If the log4j2 file is included in the ZIP that is generated by a MuleZip task, then you can simply add another `if`-branch for the log4j2 file.

But actually it is probably better to just edit the concrete task that packages up the log4j2 file into some archive instead of all tasks of the same type.

Besides that you should be able to use `filesMatching` instead of `eachFile` with an `if` I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, log4j2.xml is not in the collection in the MuleZip task. Here is the code for the task https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/mulesoft/build/MuleZip.groovy

Comment: As I said. Modify the task that packages the `log4j2.xml` file. I'd need to see your `build.gradle` and the path to the `log4j2.xml' file to suggest a concrete task to modify.

Comment: Our log4j2.xml is standardly located under "src\main\resources\log4j2.xml" Here is our build.gradle: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuv4j9htpseyed4/build.gradle?dl=0

Comment: I think what you need is `processResources { filesMatching('log4j2.xml') { filter ... } }`

Comment: Huge thanks, Vampire. It works flawlessly. Please, add it is a reply, so that I can mark it as solved. Thanks again!

Comment: I answered the question as it stands already. If you want me to add the additional information to the question you need  to add the additional information to the question. And don't use links to external resources, this is not allowed on SO afair.